# StreamQueryListener in Spark doesn't execute code from onQueryProgress()

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, etl, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm reading data from Databricks delta table as stream and writing it to another delta table (Using console in screenshot for ease of debugging), I would like to make use of StreamingQueryListener() of spark and use onQueryProgress() to print Input rows from the batch in the code snippet here for debugging. Not sure what am I missing here!

This made me think if this functionality was only for Kafka, but I got same results by using Kafka source as well. Any help is appreciated

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming._
val streamingCountsListener = new StreamingQueryListener() {
  override def onQueryStarted(queryStarted: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {
      println("query started")
  }
  override def onQueryTerminated(queryTerminated: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {
        println("query made stopped")
      
  }
  override def onQueryProgress(queryProgress: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    queryProgress.progress.sources.foreach(src => {
      println(src.numInputRows)
      println("\n\n\n\n")
    })
  }
}

// Add this query listener to the session
spark.streams.addListener(streamingCountsListener)

var x = spark.readStream.format("delta")
  .option("ignoreChanges", "true")
  .table(s"qastg.student")

val query = x.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .outputMode("append")
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz8JT.png)

Tried using Kafka Source and using simple print statements to debug, didn't work

Comment: By the way, ignoreChanges is now deprecated. When streaming from a Delta table that is being updated, it's better to use skipChangeCommits or the change data feed.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing `%scala`, I assume this is on Databricks within a notebook. If so, this information is provided [out of the box](https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/delta-lake.html#metrics-1). If you need something that's not provided by this default Databricks listener, you should be able to see your custom listener output in the [driver's stdout logs](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/clusters-manage.html#cluster-driver-and-worker-logs).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event to the query listener:

```
queryStarted: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent queryStarted
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, doing what you suggested gave me syntax error. Is tehre anything else I can try?

Comment: Try  `onQueryStarted(StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent queryStarted)`

Comment: This didn't work either